# How to modify flutter app code automatically

Tags: flutter

Is it possible that we ship the android app, which just loads a file(like `/data/data/com.example/files/data.txt`) into the memory, like we load fonts dynamically with `loadFontFronList`, which can be manually updated by the app automatically.

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not possible like you said. but there're plugins by which you can achieve dynamic code at some level.
e.g. : [Dynamic Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget) , [Json Dynamic Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/json_dynamic_widget)

Comment: Thanking you, may i also get some input regarding the 2nd point, if covered, also should i post this to github.com/dart-lang as a feature request?

Comment: Well, I m not sure about 2nd point. but you can post that thing as a feature request.